# Regex Match greedy, optional, non-capturing groups

Tags: regex

I'm trying to capture two chunks of a string but ignoring anything after if one of two tokens are found.

**Examples:**

`a/b/c` would match (1) `a/b/` and (2) `c`
`a/b` would match (1) `a/` and (2) `b`
`a` would match (1) `<nil>` and (2) `a`

So `^(.*/)*(.*)$` will do what I want there.

Where it gets complicated, If one of two tokens (`foo` or `bar`) are found, ignore everything afterwards.

**Examples:**

`a/b/c/foo/d` would ignore `/foo/d` and match (1) `a/b/` and (2) `c`
`a/b/c/bar/d` would ignore `/bar/d` and match (1) `a/b/` and (2) `c`

So I tried this: `^(.*/)*(.*)(?:/(?:foo|bar)/.*)$` and the second set of examples matches but the first doesn't... because I didn't make the second half optional.

Then I tried making it optional `^(.*/)*(.*)(?:/(?:foo|bar)/.*)?$`: and now the greediness of the first part takes over and nothing matches.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: I can't craft anything better than `^((?:(?!/(?:foo|bar)/).)*/)?([^/]*)(?:/(?:foo|bar)/.*)?$` now. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7i66Og/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Wow!  It works :)  Maybe someone can find a way to optimize it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you may use

```
^((?:(?!/(?:foo|bar)/).)*/)?([^/]*)(?:/(?:foo|bar)/.*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7i66Og/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `((?:(?!/(?:foo|bar)/).)*/)?` - Optional capturing group #1:

  - `(?:(?!/(?:foo|bar)/).)*` - any char, 0 or more occurrences (as many as possible), that does not start (i.e. is not the first char of) a `/foo/` or `/bar/` character sequence
  - `/` - a `/` char
- `([^/]*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than `/` char
- `(?:/(?:foo|bar)/.*)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `/(?:foo|bar)/` - `/foo/` or `/bar/`
  - `.*` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.